# Check to see if sharepoint document is open for editing by someone else

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have a SP2007 document library. I'm using SP Web services to pass documents (Excel WBs)  in a certain status to a program to process and then update the Workbooks. If the workbook is already open for editing, the process has to punt. I want to identify documents that are open for editing before passing them to the process, so I can skip them without instantiating Excel, etc. How do I know (using Web Services) that a document is open for editing by someone else?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if `Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile.SPCheckOutType status == 1`

Comment: Thank you, Paul. Using Web Services, do I have access to that? I don't have the Microsoft.Sharepoint reference, since my program runs remotely from the SP server. Also, when I have the workbook open, the SP page shows nothing under "Checked out by". I'll look at the web service properties and see if I see "Checkouttype"....